# Unsafe assignment/member access of an `any` value with fetch api

Tags: typescript

I don't know how to correct the linting error. Perhaps I just don't fully understand the issue, but it doesn't seem to matter what I do. I just can't seem to get rid of the error. I'd rather not disable the rule unless the issue is that my linting rules are just too strict.

I'm using this in a `fetch` with google geocode api.

```
fetch(uri)
        .then(res => (res.json() as Promise<google.maps.GeocoderResponse>))
        .then(data => {
            const result = data.results[0].geometry;
            // Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.
            // Unsafe member access .results on an `any` value.

        })
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the type of `data`?

```
.then((data: <DEFINE TYPE HERE>)  => {
            const result = data.results[0].geometry;
        })
```

Comment: I have and I get the same errors. Thanks for the reply. :D

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work

```
(data as google.maps.GeocoderResponse).results[0].geometry
```

else define custom type in typescript for geocoderresponse and use it.
[url](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-types-in-typescript)

Comment: Still the same errors. I would think that the type should be fine since it's pulling in `@types/google.maps`. I shouldn't need to define a custom type.